# Checking for an empty string

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for some guidance on checking for a string that is returning string(1) " ".

I am rendering a button in a WordPress template file. I first get the post meta, which is added via an API update. I then parse it so as to add the ID to an external booking url.

I need to test to ensure a value is returned of course. However, if I use !empty , this isn't working because even if the field has no value entered, it is still returning string(1) " " from the database.

I could test for strlen, but this doesn't seem very elegant. What would be the best way to test for this?

Many thanks

````
$s_apply_url0 = get_post_meta( $event_id, '_MyBookingURL', true);

parse_str($s_apply_url0, $output);

$s_apply_url1 = 'https://mybookings.com/event/' . $output ['id'];

 if (!empty($s_apply_url0): ?>
          <aside id="applybutton-2" class=" grop-side-widget widget_applybutton">
            <a href="<?= $s_apply_url1; ?>" class="btn course-apply">
              <?= $s_apply_text1 ?>
            </a>
          </aside>
        <?php endif; ?> ```
````

Comment: A string with a single space in it is not an empty string :) Its a string with a single space in it, thats at least 1 byte

Comment: How about `if (!empty(trim($input))) { ....`? See: [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood this question correctly, you want to be able to test whether *the string is empty or contains more than one space characters*

You could [first use the `trim` function of PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) in order to 'trim' the string of whitespace (or, arbitrarily any other characters you wish to determine as 'blank').

```php
<?php

if (empty(trim($myString)) {
    // the string is empty, or contains only whitespace
}
```

If you wish to ONLY test for a single ' ' character, then you could just add that into your conditions, eg:

```php
<?php
if (empty($myString) || $myString === ' ') {
    // $myString is empty or only contains a single space character
}
```